# How do I move Laravel Mix Build notification window to the bottom of the page

Tags: laravel, webpack

How do i move the annoying build window to the bottom of the page this is what my webpack file looks like

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");

    mix.js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
        .postCss("resources/css/main.css", "public/css", [
            require("tailwindcss"),
            require("autoprefixer")
        ])
        .version()
        .browserSync({ proxy: "localhost:8000" }
        );
```

thanks

Comment: Those are OS notifications, I don't think you can change the place from laravel, but in the  operating system settings

Answer (score 1):

Easy. Simply add this line to your file

```
mix.disableNotifications();
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#notifications

Comment: the question is asking move to the bottom of the page, not disable it.

Comment: I want it to display at the bottom of the page not disable it

Comment: Sorry @CYBERSIX you are out of luck. If they are so annoying, disabling them is your only option. As the comment in the question says this are OS notifications.